# Navigation in UWP app

Tags: uwp-xaml, windows-template-studio

I've written a UWP app using VS2017 and Windows Template Studio.  I've created multiple pages by using the Pivot Page Navigation Template.

Here is the basic code:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        ///Update controls here

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I've added the "OnNavigatedTo" method, but it doesn't get called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you use Pivot Page Navigation Template to create the UWP project, it will create `PivotPage` in the View folder. And it will set the MainPage in the `PivotItem` in `PivotPage`.

The `OnNavigatedTo` invoked when the Page is loaded and becomes the current source of a parent Frame. When you switch the pages, the current source of a parent Frame will not change.

If you write `OnNavigatedTo` in the `PivotPage`, it will be called when you launched the app. You should be able to add `Loaded` event in the `MainPage`, it occurs when the page has been constructed and added to the object tree, and is ready for interaction.

Comment: Thanks Jayden,  I added the Page_Loaded to the Main Page and it gets called the initial load, but does not get called if I return  I need to see every time Main Page is returned to from any of the individual alternate pages.

Comment: @TreyBalut You should be able to use `SelectionChanged` event in `Pivot`, it occurs when the selected PivotItem changed.